# Why “kion” instead of “kiun” in this sentence?

Tags: literature

In the *Fundamenta Krestomatio* (“La naskiĝo de la tabako”), I found the following sentence:

> Ve al vi, kiu tiel malbone volas repagi la bonaĵon, **kion** oni faras al vi!

I know there are differences between the Esperanto of that time and today’s Esperanto (*centjaro* instead of *jarcento*, *elrigardi* instead of *aspekti*, *pli-ol-unu* instead of *pluraj*, *bovoviro* instead of *virbovo*, *ĝi* used like *tio*, etc.) but this struck me as particularly odd. From my understanding and from the context of the story, *kion* refers to *la bonaĵon*, not *repagi la bonaĵon*, so it should be *kiun* instead. I think. I thought it was a typo, but I’m reading from the sixth (1909) edition (p. 36), and I found it in the Tekstaro as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of *kio* instead of *kiu* with reference to a single noun here is simply wrong. There are [cases that may look like such a use](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/kiu_kio_kies/kio.html#j-jef), but this is not the case here.
In the 18th edition of the *Fundamenta Krestomatio*, annotated by Gaston Waringhien, *kion* is corrected to *kiun* in a footnote.

The text was translated in the first years of Esperanto, it was first published in *La Esperantisto* in 1893. The wrong use of the pronoun here is either due to an individual mistake of the translator or due to the fact that the norm was not totally fixed in these early days - I can't tell without a thorough study.

Please note that the *Tekstaro* does neither correct nor annotate texts, so it contains also linguistic errors and bad style, if they were in the original text, although most of the texts collected there are of a good quality.

Comment: You suggested it could be an individual mistake of the translator. Isn't it written at the beginning of the *Fundamenta Krestomatio* that Zamenhof corrected the texts by other authors in order to fit his own style? If that's the case, then it doesn't look likely to me that Zamenhof would have let such a mistake stay.

Comment: Zamenhof was very refraining and  did not thoroughly correct the texts, however. If you look at the book edition of the Fundamenta Krestomatio, you will see a bunch of grammatical errors corrected in the footnotes by Waringhien (e.g. in the last text, the Iliad), which should have been corrected already by Z.

Comment: I think this additional information makes your answer the most complete there can be. Dankon!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that it very well have been a typographical mistake. In this context, *kiu* is the only one that is appropriate, and I've never heard of *kio* being used in its stead in this sort of situation. *Kio* can be used to create dependant clauses if reflexive of *tio*, but in the case of actual nouns, *kiu* should be used.

„Ve al vi, kiu tiel malbone volas repagi la bonaĵon, *kiun* oni faras al vi!“ would have been more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

*Kiun* would be a selection from several. Here probably just one *bonaĵo* was paid.

Simple as that, though intuitively I would have used *kiun* too. Compare:

> Ve al vi, kiu tiel malbone volas repagi *tion*, kion oni faras al vi!

If one could have written

> Ve al vi, kiu tiel malbone volas repagi tiun bonaĵon, kiun oni faras al vi!

the case would be different.